# File.Move and WebBrowser

Tags: c#, file, browser

Relatively new to C# - TIA for any help.

Building window app with a webBrowser.  Using `browser.Navigate("myfilestring")` to get to a local file (PDF for what that may matter).  After viewing the file, I want to have a method to `File.Move()` the file from one directory to another.  The issue I am having is that the Move returns an IO exception stating that the file operation cannot be performed as the file is being used by another process.

Prior to the call to the Move, I `browser.Navigate("someotherfilestring")` in the hopes of freeing the 'file in use' lock on the original file...doesn't help.

I've also put a recursive try/catch around the Move and put a `thread.sleep(50)` in the catch in further hopes that it was just a timing issue...no help, either.

However, if I put a `MessageBox.Show()` in the catch - the IO exception catches one time - get the message box displayed, and then hitting the OK button has the effect of unbusying the file to allow the `File.Move()` operation to proceed.  I'd rather not have the box pop up as the solution.

Any hints as to how I can programatically unbusy the file to allow the `File.Move()` operation to proceed?

Thanks again.

Comment: The common Adobe software workaround: Process.Kill() on acroread.exe

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest structuring your program in such a way where you can avoid the problem all together:

- When you navigate to the file, first use `File.Copy()` to copy the file to a temporary location with a unique filename.
- Navigate to the Temp File
- When you go to do `File.Move()`, everything should work just fine, as it is now the Temp file that is locked, rather than the original file.

Comment: @user1038683, thank you--glad it helps. If you feel this answers your question, please upvote it and/or accept it as the answer.